# distance between caption and table (ACM SIG)

Tags: tables, captions

I'm using ACM SIG format in LaTeX (editing the sample).
I want to add tables, and i did, but the distance between caption and table is weird.

**Table 1** is fine, but the space in between is too small for **Table 2**. How do I fix it?

[image]

Code for table:

```
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\caption{Some Typical Commands} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline Command&A Number&Comments\\ \hline \texttt{{\char'134}alignauthor} & 100& Author alignment\\ \hline \texttt{{\char'134}numberofauthors}& 200& Author enumeration\\ \hline \texttt{{\char'134}table}& 300 & For tables\\ \hline \texttt{{\char'134}table*}& 400& For wider tables\\ \hline\end{tabular} \end{table}
```

I'm using `sig-alternate-05-2015` document class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that none of the letters in the second caption happen to have a descender component, i.e., a component that protrudes below the baseline. I suggest you change the second `\caption` instruction to

```
\caption{Parameters of DRAM and NAND Flash\strut}
```

The directive `\strut`, which is provided by the LaTeX kernel, inserts a (what else?) "typographic strut", with a depth of `0.3\baselineskip` and a height of `0.7\baselineskip` (and zero width, making the object invisible).

---

Here's an MWE that use the `sig-alternate-05-2015` document class. Observe the difference that having a `\strut` directive makes for the position of the second caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\newcommand\mytab{% a little test tabular...
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Parameter & DRAM & NAND Flash\\
    \hline
    Access Latency & 40ns & 1.5 (ms/blk) \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Parameters of DRAM and NAND Flash}
\mytab

\bigskip

\caption{Parameters of DRAM and NAND Flash\strut}
\mytab

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: omg! im using exact the same document class! it works perfectly :) Thank you so much!!

Comment: @ShimHyunjeong - Good to know that my guess as to the document class was correct. :-)